# How do I change state of Single<T> object in a reactive way?

Tags: rxjs, rx-java, reactive-programming

How can I rewrite this function in a reactive way (I don't really like modifying the object within `.doOnNext`(:

```
Single<List<Integer>> getListSingle()
{
    return Observable.range(0, new Random().nextInt())
                     .toList()
                     .doOnSuccess(list -> {
                         if (list.size() < 10) {
                             list.add(123);
                         }
                     });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The case seems a little contrived but you could always copy the immutable object in `map`:

```
Observable.range(0, new Random().nextInt())
        .toList()
        .map(integers -> {
            if (integers.size() < 10) {
                List<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<>(integers);
                copy.add(123);
                return copy;
            } else {
                return integers;
            }
        });
```